# How copy one table contents to another, ignoring PK duplicates when i don't know column set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 databases: SRC and DST. Each one contains table DATA an in every database DATA's columns sets are equal, but it's unknown for user (I don't know name of PK or even is PK identity or single).

I already have the following script:

```
insert into DST.dbo.DATA select * from SRC.dbo.DATA
```

But if DST.DATA contains rows with same PK it throws an error (I'm using C#). That's why i want to use something like

```
on duplicate ignore
```

from mysql

Could you please advice me script that copies rows from SRC.dbo.DATA to DST.dbo.DATA ignoring primary key constraints. And if possible, foreign constraints too

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
insert into DST.dbo.DATA 
select  s.* 
from    SRC.dbo.DATA s LEFT JOIN
        DST.dbo.DATA  d ON  s.Keys1 = d.Keys1
                        AND s.Keys2 = d.Keys2
                        ...
                        AND s.KeysN = d.KeysN
WHERE   d.Keys1 IS NULL
```

This should allow you to only insert values from Source, that is not in Destination.

Comment: Select s.*   Why do comments have to be 15 characters in length?

Comment: Thank you for response,  but problem is that I don't know column set for table. I don't know primary key for table DATA (because really i repeat this action for 20-40 different tables)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, to not select from `SRC` which is existing in `DST`.

```
insert into DST.dbo.DATA select * from SRC.dbo.DATA 
WHERE SRC.dbo.DATA.PKColumn NOT IN(SELECT PKColumn FROM DST.dbo.DATA)
```

Comment: Thank you for response,  but problem is that I don't know column set for table. I don't know primary key for table DATA (because really i repeat this action for 20-40 different tables)